# При парсинге не работает команда soup.find('div' , class_ = "css-3jcp5o ewrty961")

Tags: python, парсер

Новичок. Не судите строго. Учусь парсить сайты. Написал вот такой код:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://surgut.drom.ru/lada/all/'
r = requests.get(url)
r.text
# ------------------------------------------
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text , 'lxml')
soup
# ------------------------------------------

soup.find('div' , class_ = "css-3jcp5o ewrty961")
```

после написания вот этой строки:

```
soup.find('div' , class_ = "css-3jcp5o ewrty961")
```

ожидалось что выйдет определенный кусок кода страницы (основные характеристики машины), но ничего не происходит. Код игнорируется. Пишу в Anaconda Navigator. Пробовал перезагрузить ядро - не помогло. Библиотеки все установлены.

Answer (score -1):

следовала указать не тег не "div", а "a"